# How to retrieve a Date on Firestore without updating it with Time Zone?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following list on `Firestore`:

[image]

"schedules" display to users the dates they can make an appointment. But when the user has a different Time Zone it'll automatically update the hour. For example, someone living in Germany would receive the list 4 or 5 hours forward (06:00 would go to 10:00, 09:00 to 13:00, 11:00 to 15:00, ...). So my question is how is it possible to not interfere on the Date, not changing it's time, just to receive "the original" date it was stored?

Comment: Are you sure you want to display 06:00 for the user in Germany? Image setting up a conference call with people in Brazil, Germany and Tokyo. If they all saw the time as "06:00" then they would all show up at different times and no call would take place.

What you'll often see on websites for World Cup or Olympics is a time which can toggle between local time and the user's own time zone.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva Now I'm using the regular way, which is letting the system correct the hour, but the idea was that if anyone would schedule with a specific time, the user would be notified that the schedule was related to the timezone, which was to make clear that even though a German phone would be 06 and the appointment 06 too, you would have to see the time of the place you had an appointment. Of course, it is something presencial, so you would know eventually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when the user has a different Time Zone it'll automatically update the hour. For example, someone living in Germany would receive the list 4 or 5 hours forward

Firestore timestamps stores only the offset from the Unix epoch with a nanoseconds precision. It doesn't have any timezone encoded into them, that's why you have this behavior. Not only in Firestore but in many other databases the timestamp objects don't care about the timezone, it's all about a "point in time".

To check this out, please open Firebase console and check the value of a timestamp property. What you'll see is that the time is displayed using the local timezone that your device is apart of. Please also note that it doesn't matter in which timezone the client is. A "point in time" is the same no matter where the user is around the world.

If you are converting in your Android application the timestamp to a `Date` object, that date object will be converted itself in the user device's local timezone, similar to what is happening in the console.

If you want to get the `Date` object that corresponds to a specific timezone, you should use some specialized classes such as [TimeZone](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone). Here you have a list of all available [time zones](https://gist.github.com/arpit/1035596).

Comment: So truthfully I won't be able to retrieve the date with the Hour and Minute as it was originally stored (with the same numbers). In every call from db, the system will automatically update the time to it's local time zone and it's not a simple task to verify each local time zone to make the correct adjustment. I'll have to make something happen. Thanks Alex

Comment: *So truthfully I won't be able to retrieve the date with the Hour and Minute as it was originally stored*: Yes you can by storing the date in any other format, as a String for example but it's not a recommended approach.